# Access Validation.HasError from UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

could someone help me, how can I access the HasError property from my custom usercontrol?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,2" />
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10"
                                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white">
                            </TextBlock>-->
                        </Border>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="Layout" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="TbHostname" Grid.Column="1"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="200">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Hostname" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <serverStarter2:HostnameValidator ErrorMessage="Wrong hostname format."/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

This is my custom usercontrol, that is used in **MainWindow.xaml**. What I want, when everything is fine, enable submit button, when not, disable it.

Here is code for button inside **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Button Content="Test connection" Command="{Binding ConnectionViewModel.TestConnectionCommand}"
                          >
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=StudioHostname}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
```

ElementName=StudioHostname is name of my UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `Validation.HasError` attached property of the `TextBox` in the `UserControl` that is being set to `true`. The `Validation.HasError` property of the `UserControl` itself won't be set and you can't bind to an element that is defined the `UserControl` from the `MainWindow` using an `ElementName`.

You are doing this wrong. What you should do is to implement the validation in the view model class where the `Hostname` property is defined. You can do this by implementing the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Then you can simply bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button` to the `HasErrors` property of the view model, or bind it to an `ICommand` whose `CanExecute` method returns the value of the `HasErrors` property.

There is an example of how to implement the interface available here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it

Comment: I'm little bit confused. For my usercontrol I don't have any VM. Hostname is dependencyproperty. Do you mean I should inherit UserControl from INofityDataErrorInfo and implement the interface?

Comment: In that case, yes. The UserControl should implement the interface. You can then bind to the HasErrors property of the UserControl.